# Can we pass functions in lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

See the following code:

```
list1 = ["in", "france", "germany"]
list2 = ["NAMASTE", "VANAKAM"]
list3 = ["fr1", "fr2", "fr3"]
list4 = ["gem1","gem2", "gem3","gem4"]

def list2(): 
    return list2
def list3():    
    return list3
def list4(): 
    return list4

list5 = [list2(), list3(), list4()]
list = []
for item in range(len(list1)):
      list.append({list1[item]:list5[item]}) 
print(list)
```

The output of the above code is:

> [{'in': function list2 at |  0x7f7b5dd3be60}, {'france': function list3 at 0x7f7b5dd53170}, {'germany': function list4 at 0x717b5dcd8050}]

I was expecting this output:

> [{"in":["NAMASTE", "VANAKAM" ] }, {"france":["fr1", "fr2", "fr3" ] }, {"germany":["gem1", "gem2", "gem3", 'gem4'] } ]

Why am I not getting this output?

Comment: Your functions have the same names as your lists. You’re thus redefining (overriding) your variable names.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Please link the documentation where it is written.

Comment: Please consider using a Python linter, especially while you learn Python but ideally always. You can typically automate this in your code editor. There are 23 problems with your 17 lines of code, for example. Some of them, including the redefinition issues at the core of your problem, are genuinely errors.

Comment: @jarmod Well, I was just trying something different.

Comment: @jarmod Why did the first output come in that way? - Like ```function list3 at 0x7f7b5dd53170```

Comment: That's what happens when you print a function e.g. `print(list3)` because `list3` is now a function, and it's at address 0x7f7b5dd5317. it's not a list any more. You redefined it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KonradRudolph said, you are overriding list names with function names. You can solve the issue by correcting the function names.

```
list1 = ["in", "france", "germany"]
list2 = ["NAMASTE", "VANAKAM"]
list3 = ["fr1", "fr2", "fr3"]
list4 = ["gem1","gem2", "gem3","gem4"]

def list_2():
    return list2
def list_3():
    return list3
def list_4():
    return list4

list5 = [list_2(), list_3(), list_4()]
list = []
for item in range(len(list1)):
      list.append({list1[item]:list5[item]})
print(list)
```

Output:

```
[{'in': ['NAMASTE', 'VANAKAM']}, {'france': ['fr1', 'fr2', 'fr3']}, {'germany': ['gem1', 'gem2', 'gem3', 'gem4']}]
```

Below code might help to understand better,

```
list2 = ["NAMASTE", "VANAKAM"]

def list2():
    return list2

list5 = [list2()]

print (id(list2))
print (id(list2()))

print(id(list2) == id(list2()))
```

Output:

```
59855176
59855176
True
```

Which means memory address for both the items are same and hence it does not call the function.

Comment: Please give a link to the documentation where it is written.

Comment: Why did the first output come in that way? - Like function list3 at 0x7f7b5dd53170

Comment: Since the function returns the value , the output shows the list3  as function and its memory location.

Comment: Please give a link to the python documentation where it is written.

Comment: @NirajRaut Where *what* is written?

Comment: @NirajRaut  if you check the id of function name and variable than you will understand that both are pointing to same memory location. I have updated the above code. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the following lint issues. All of them are coding errors:

1. function already defined line 2 [6, 1]
2. function already defined line 3 [8, 1]
3. function already defined line 4 [10, 1]
4. Redefining built-in 'list' [14, 1]
5. Bad indentation. Found 6 spaces, expected 4 [16, 1]